# How does the state government's organizational structure chart look like in India?

Tags: government, india

Need to understand the categories and positions like a flow chart from **`Chief minister`** to the low-level cadre of the Government in India.

I searched for it in Google but nowhere found it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not seeing a ready-made organizational chart for the state level as a whole, but here are some ideas for how you might piece one together.

Directly under the Chief Minister you would have the Council of Ministers, [which currently lists 31 members in the case of Tamil Nadu](https://www.tn.gov.in/ministerslist). Under those ministers you would find department commissioners, and most of the departments have their own organizational charts. [Here](https://ctd.tn.gov.in/documents/10184/30502/Organisational+Structure/37037532-dc90-45ea-b68a-4fa44e2f499b?version=1.5)'s one for the Department of Commercial Taxes, [another](http://www.stationeryprinting.tn.gov.in/orgn_chart.htm) for the Stationary and Printing Department, just to give some examples. [Here](https://www.tn.gov.in/contact_directory/department_contact/All) is a list of all the departments that have web pages. The [full contact directory](https://www.tn.gov.in/contact_directory) might help you fill in some of the other branches of the tree.